# How to group by, sum up by one member and map to a list of a new object?

Tags: kotlin

I have a list of objects like this:

```
val obj1 = Obj(date = LocalDate.parse("2018-12-12"), amount = BigDecimal(100))
val obj2 = Obj(date = LocalDate.parse("2018-12-12"), amount = BigDecimal(200))
val obj3 = Obj(date = LocalDate.parse("2019-10-10"), amount = BigDecimal(500))

val arrayOfObj = arrayOf(obj1, obj2, obj3)
```

I would like to return a list of objects that look something like this:

```
date=2018-12-12, amount=300, objs=[Obj(date=2018-12-12, amount=100), Obj(date=2018-12-12, amount=200)]
date=2019-10-10, amount=500, objs=[Obj(date=2019-10-10, amount=500)]
```

Basically I would like to groupBy date, sum up the amounts, and map to a new object, which includes a list of the orignal objects

arrayOfObj.groupBy {it.date} gives me a nice map, and I can loop the entries and get the amount, but I am wondering if there is a slick way to do this with fold or aggregate. I'm a bit of a Kotlin n00b.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As you imagined, there's a way to use `fold` to calculate the total amount of each group since `sumBy` doesn't exist for `BigDecimal`:

```kotlin
arrayOfObj.groupBy { it.date }.map { (date, objs) ->
    // Sums the amount of the objects of this group.
    val totalAmount = objs.fold(BigDecimal.ZERO) { acc, obj -> acc + obj.amount }
    // I've used a Kotlin Triple here but you can use your custom class.
    Triple(date, totalAmount, objs)
}
```

Comment: Beautiful and simple. Thank you for the quick reply <3

Comment: @SomaiahKumbera No problem!

Comment: Personally, I'd factor out a one-liner extension function for `sumBy` on `BigDecimal`; it'd make the rest more readable, and be reusable too.